# How do you check if multiple rectangles overlap?

Tags: java, arrays, rectangles

```
Square[] testSquares = new Square[3];

public SquareTester (){
    for(int i = 0; i < testSquares.length; i++){
        testSquares[i] = new Square();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i<testSquares.length; i++){
        testSquares[i].display(g);
    }

    if (testSquares[0].overlaps(testSquares[1])) {
        testSquares[0].changeColor(Color.YELLOW);
        testSquares[1].changeColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.setFont(new Font ("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD,35));
        g.drawString("HOLA, IT OVERLAPPED!", 0, 600);
    }
}
```

Above is the code that makes the array of squares, and changes color when two of them overlap. I want to change this code so that it changes color if any of the squares in the whole array are overlapping. (My overlaps method is done already. No need to code that.)

Comment: So, you need us to code up the `.overlaps()` method for you, eh?

Comment: 2 for loops checking testSquare[i] vs testSquare[j] wouldn't do it ? I don't see how you would need help for that...

Comment: not sure what the question is tbh

Comment: Test for overlapping inside the for loop before you render? And test for all other squares and not just [0] and [1]

Comment: You need to create a rectangle which occupies the overlapping space and render it on the `Graphics` pane. If you change `overlaps` to return the top left and bottom right coordinates of the intersecting rectangle (and null if there is no overlap), you already have the dimensions of the intersect. Just create a `Rectangle` object to those dimensions, and render it.

Comment: As an aside, why comic sans? Bold comic sans noless. Surely there is a better way......

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    boolean[] overlap = new boolean[testSquares.length];
    for (int i=0; i<testSquares.length; i++)
    {
        if(!overlap[i])
        {
            for (int j=i; j<testSquares.length; j++)
            {
                if(testSquares[i].overlaps(testSquares[j]))
                {
                    overlap[i] = overlap[j] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // now use overlap to display squares as overlapped or not
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't provide the dimensions of the intersecting rectangles, just a list of bools denoting which overlap. The overlapping areas would therefore need to be calculated in another loop iterating over the `overlap` array. If instead an array of `Rectangle` was created, the overlapping area could be calculated in the main loop, and rendering is just a case of iterating the rectangles and drawing them